# False proposition then true

Tags: calculus, logic

Please, take a look to this inequation (m is a natural number):

$$2\sqrt {m+1} - 2\sqrt m \lt\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}} $$

For m = 3, the expression is false:

0.53 $\lt$ 0.5

So, the expression doesn't hold for all naturals.

But we have this:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}} \lt\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$$

Which holds for every natural number.

So, we have now:

$$2\sqrt {m+1} - 2\sqrt m \lt\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}} \lt\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$$

Then:

$$2\sqrt {m+1} - 2\sqrt m  \lt\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$$

Which is true for all naturals.

How we can get a true propositon, from a false one?

Am I missing something?

(I arrived to this trying to prove a a proposition from the Calculus book by Apostol)

Comment: As someone else said, you can not use a false proposition and expect to reach a true result.

Comment: From false hyphotesis everything may follow. $1\leq -1$ is a false premise, but nonetheless, by squaring both sides we get $1\leq 1$ that is a true inequality. So, no wonder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially what you are doing:

(a) $2 < 1$ is false.

(b) $1 < 1000$ is true.

From (a) and (b) we get $2 < 1 < 1000$ which is nonsense/false.

We cut away the failing middle part and are left with $2 < 1000$ which is true.

Comment: Ok, but you know that 2 < 1000 is true. In the example, I don´t know that $2\sqrt {m+1} - 2\sqrt m  \lt\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$ is true. I got the trueness from a false statement. Is the whole demostration wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are by accident reaching a true statement.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get the true proposition from the false one. It would be kind of like saying $2 < 1$ is not true but $1 < 3$ is true so $2 < 3$ is true. You didn't get it from $2 < 1 < 3$. It exists as its own statement.

Comment: But, with some manipulation I arrived to the false proposition, which let me demostrate that $2\sqrt {m+1} - 2\sqrt m  \lt\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$. The demostration is wrong?

Comment: If I understand what you mean by your demonstration then, yes, it's wrong. At some point you say "then we have now $2\sqrt{m+1}-2\sqrt{m} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$ which is just simply not true.

Answer (score 0):

Actually
$$  \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}} \lt\ 2\sqrt {m+1} - 2\sqrt m \lt\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$$
because
$$  2\sqrt {m+1} - 2\sqrt m = \frac{2}{\sqrt {m+1} + \sqrt m} $$
and
$$  \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}} \lt\  \frac{2}{\sqrt {m+1} + \sqrt m} \lt\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Deductive reasoning has the **soundness** property, which states that "from true sentences and valid inference rules only true statements are derived", however it doesn't state that "from false statements and valid inference rules only false statements are derived", because **soundness** preserves only truth but not falsity.

Therefore it is possible that you derive either a true or a false statement from any false statements.

Actually, from false statements you could derive **anything** (through the use of *reductio ad absurdum*).